# Store ui related properties outside of the component state

Tags: reactjs

I've moved from using pure jsons in react to instances.
Meaning, I store instances inside the component state.
The problem is that the instances can't update their own properties because it means mutating the state so I need to clone the instance, update from outside of the instance, and then set state.

I wanted to store the instances on the component and store a dummy state property that once an instance property changes it updates the dummy state that will trigger a re-render.

Since the instances are related to the UI I know they should reside in the state.

I know it's not the best practice but I'm trying to figure out how bad is it.

For example:

```
class Team {
  constructor(data) {
    this._teamMates = null;
    this.id = data.id;
  }

  get teamMates() {
    if (!this._teamMates) {
      this.fetchTeamMates();
      return null;
    }
    else 
      return this._teamMates;
  }

  fetchTeamMates() {
    fetch('/teamMates/' + this.id).then(teamMates => this._teamMates = teamMates);
  }
}
```

When we first try to get teamMated they are not valid so we fetch them and on the next state change I want them to be valid as teamMates.

I can return a promise instead of null, it is possible but I want to handle it this way because I want to have conditional rendering if we have the teamMates.

I know there are multiple ways to solve this thing but I rather try to find a way to make it work without returning a promise.

Comment: Can you show how you are planning to update the instances, and where you create them? I guess theoretically you could pass the instances a callback that triggers upon updating it's properties (like forceUpdate or a setState call). As long you know it's not best practice ;)

Comment: The problem came up when I had a promise inside the instance that when it got resolved it updated the value inside the instance (=mutation), so now I plan to take the instance out of the state and pass the setState to the constructor, plus,  implement a method called "updateMe()" inside the instance and it will update a state called 'timestamp' (for example) that will trigger the re-render.

Comment: It seems to me you are avoiding the cause of the problem and looking for a workaround. I would be curious to see the original code that gave you a problem. Personally, I think you might have more a problem of taking the correct statemanagement engine (component state isn't the only one available)

Comment: updated dear friend @Icepickle

Comment: I really wonder if you need to have your own class instances for team mates. I understand though that it feels more like the old ways of doing things, but with some state management libraries, this would be very easy, maybe I could give a response for an alternative solution using redux or just with component state and props for children...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by:

"The problem is that the instances can't update their own properties because it means mutating the state so I need to clone the instance, update from outside of the instance, and then set state."

It sounds like the simplest thing to do is create the state and method in a parent HOC, pass them to a child component and fire the action in an event handler, it should then update the parents state and cause the normal render in the child. Ideally your child would be a "dumb component", literally just passing the values and actions and rendering.

Comment: Bear in mind I'm taking about instances that are not components.
I'm taking about storing a 'regular' class instance inside the state and because it's inside the state you have to update properties via cloning the instance and calling setState.
Hope I made it somehow clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for some state manager, like redux for example (you didn't exclude it from your question)

If you really want to keep your own instances (what I don't see as a necessity, as it is in no way necessary, you are handling with state), then you should create an immutable version of your classes, meaning, if you update a player inside your team, you should return a new version of your team instance, with the changed player data.

The below example doesn't use an instance, but it moves the team mates to a store, and lets redux manage the state (so it removes it from component state).

Main key points to focus on would be:

The `connect` statement, connecting a component with a (part of) state injected in its props, and adding a `dispatcher` that handles the actions you dispatch to it, looking like this:

```
const ConnectedTeamEditor = connect( teamStateToProps, playerDispatcher )( TeamEditor );
```

This requires then ofcourse a state mapper and the dispatcher, which looks pretty much like this:

```
// dispatcher for the actions
const playerDispatcher = dispatch => ({
  fetch() {
    return getTeamMates().then( response => dispatch( { type: 'loaded', payload: response } ) );
  },
  update( player ) {
    dispatch( { type: 'update', payload: player } );
  }
});

// state mapper, sharing teamMates state over the connected components props
const teamStateToProps = state => ({ teamMates: state.teamMates });
```

To handle the dispatch calls, we would need a reducer that is then also registered into a store, and we use the `createStore` method provided by react-redux. The reducer can have a default state

```
// reducer for player actions
const playerReducer = ( state = { teamMates: null }, action ) => {
  switch ( action.type ) {
    case 'loaded':
      return { teamMates: action.payload };
    case 'update':
      return { teamMates: state.teamMates.map( player => player.id === action.payload.id ? action.payload : player ) };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

// and registration to store
const appStore = createStore( playerReducer );
```

React-redux will automatically update the affected components, once their state gets updated. Important to note is that state shouldn't be mutated, it should be replaced when required. It is also important that the state is returned when no matching `action.type` was found.

Finally, the application should be wrapped with a `Provider` that receives the `store` through its props, and that would then look like that.

```
ReactDOM.render( <Provider store={appStore}><ConnectedTeamEditor /></Provider>, target );
```

I do keep a component state, but only for updating the selected player at the time.

As most of us are in WK mood, I kinda went freestyle on the design, just run the code to see what I mean ^_^

```js
const { createStore } = Redux;
const { Provider, connect } = ReactRedux;

// data provider
function getTeamMates() {
  return Promise.resolve([
    { id: 1, firstName: 'Romelu', lastName: 'Lukaku', position: 'forward' },
    { id: 2, firstName: 'Dries', lastName: 'Mertens', position: 'forward' },
    { id: 3, firstName: 'Eden', lastName: 'Hazard', position: 'forward' },
    { id: 4, firstName: 'Radja', lastName: 'Naingolan', position: 'midfield' },
    { id: 5, firstName: 'Kevin', lastName: 'De Bruyne', position: 'midfield' },
    { id: 6, firstName: 'Jordan', lastName: 'Lukaku', position: 'defender' },
    { id: 7, firstName: 'Axel', lastName: 'Witsel', position: 'midfield' },
    { id: 8, firstName: 'Vincent', lastName: 'Kompany', position: 'defender' },
    { id: 9, firstName: 'Thomas', lastName: 'Meunier', position: 'defender' },
    { id: 10, firstName: 'Marouane', lastName: 'Fellaini', position: 'midfield' },
    { id: 11, firstName: 'Thibaut', lastName: 'Courtois', position: 'Goalie' }
  ]);
}

// some container to translate the properties to readable names
const labels = {
  'id': '#',
  'firstName': 'First Name',
  'lastName': 'Last Name',
  'position': 'Position'
};

// small function to return the correct translation or default value
const translateProperty = ( property ) => labels[property] || property;

// a field that is either editable or just shows a span with a value
const Field = ({ isEditable, value, onChange }) => {
  if ( isEditable ) {
    return <span className="value">
      <input type="text" value={ value } onChange={ e => onChange( e.target.value ) }  />
    </span>;
  }
  return <span className="value">{ value }</span>;
};

// a single player, delegating changes to its data and selection style
const Player = ({ player, isSelected, onChange, onSelect }) => {
  return (
    <div className={classNames('row', { isSelected })} onClick={ () => !isSelected && onSelect && onSelect( player ) }>
    { Object.keys( player ).map( property => (
      <div className="cell" key={property}>
        <span className="label">{ translateProperty( property ) }</span>
        <Field 
          isEditable={isSelected && property !== 'id' }
          value={ player[property] }
          onChange={ newValue => onChange( {...player, [property]: newValue } ) }
        />
      </div>
    ) ) }
    </div>
  );
};

// reducer for player actions
const playerReducer = ( state = { teamMates: null }, action ) => {
  switch ( action.type ) {
    case 'loaded':
      return { teamMates: action.payload };
    case 'update':
      return { teamMates: state.teamMates.map( player => player.id === action.payload.id ? action.payload : player ) };
    case 'add':
      return { teamMates: state.teamMates.concat( [ {
        id: state.teamMates.reduce( (c, i) => c > i.id ? c : i.id, 0 ) + 1,
        ...action.payload } ] ) };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

// dispatcher for the actions
const playerDispatcher = dispatch => ({
  fetch() {
    return getTeamMates().then( response => dispatch( { type: 'loaded', payload: response } ) );
  },
  update( player ) {
    dispatch( { type: 'update', payload: player } );
  },
  add( player ) {
    dispatch( { type: 'add', payload: player } );
  }
});

const teamStateToProps = state => ({ teamMates: state.teamMates });

// the team editor that works with props
class TeamEditor extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectedPlayer: null,
      newPlayer: null
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    // load when mounting
    this.props.fetch();
  }
  selectPlayer( player ) {
    // component state keeps the selected player
    this.setState( { selectedPlayer: player } );
  }
  updatePlayer( player ) {
    // update player through dispatcher
    this.props.update( player );
  }
  
  onAddClicked() {
    this.setState( { 
      isAdding: true, 
      newPlayer: { 
        firstName: '', 
        lastName: '', 
        position: '' 
      } 
    } );
  }
  
  updateNewPlayer( player ) {
    this.setState( { newPlayer: player } );
  }
  
  savePlayer() {
    this.setState( { isAdding: false } , () => this.props.add( this.state.newPlayer ) );
  }
  
  cancelChanges() {
    this.setState( { isAdding: false } );
  }
  
  render() {
    const { teamMates} = this.props;
    const { selectedPlayer, isAdding, newPlayer } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="team">
        <div className="row">
          { !isAdding && <button 
              type="button" 
              onClick={ () => this.onAddClicked() }>Add team member</button> 
          }
          { isAdding && <span>
              <button 
                type="button"
                onClick={ () => this.savePlayer() }>Save</button>
              <button 
                type="button"
                onClick={ () => this.cancelChanges() }>Cancel</button>
            </span> }
        </div>
        { isAdding && <div className="row">
          <Player 
            isSelected
            player={newPlayer}
            onChange={ (...args) => this.updateNewPlayer( ...args ) } />
        </div> }
        { teamMates && teamMates.map( player => (
          <Player 
            key={player.id} 
            isSelected={ !isAdding && selectedPlayer && selectedPlayer.id === player.id } 
            player={player} 
            onChange={ (...args) => this.updatePlayer( ...args ) } 
            onSelect={ (...args) => this.selectPlayer( ...args ) }
          /> ) ) }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// connect the teameditor with state and dispatcher
const ConnectedTeamEditor = connect( teamStateToProps, playerDispatcher )( TeamEditor );

// create a simple store, no middleware
const appStore = createStore( playerReducer );

const target = document.querySelector('#container');
ReactDOM.render( <Provider store={appStore}><ConnectedTeamEditor /></Provider>, target );
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-content: center;
}
.row:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.row.isSelected > .cell > * {
  background-image: linear-gradient( rgba( 225, 225, 225, 0.7 ), rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.9 ) );
}
.cell {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  align-self: flex-start;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.cell:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}
.cell:last-child {
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
}
.cell > span {
  padding: 5px;
}
.cell > span > input {
  width: 100%;
}
.label {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<script id="react" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.2/react.js"></script>
<script id="react-dom" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<script id="classnames" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/classnames/2.2.5/index.js"></script>
<script id="redux" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/3.7.2/redux.js"></script>
<script id="react-redux" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/5.0.6/react-redux.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm using redux in my app.

Comment: The problem is for when I want to open a view for creating a new teamMate, while the inputs are not done I hold the instance in the local component state and until I dispatch it I need it to stay locally in the component

Comment: @Loves2Develop but that seems like a different problem than you described in your initial question. Just creating an action that adds a player should be enough

Comment: @Loves2Develop I added a sample of local saving state before dispatching, I did however use the existing component I had anyhow written already, so it might be a bit "hacky" :)